# How to move turtlebot for a certain pre-defined distance

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

We would like to write a code that makes Turtlebot move linearly to a specified distance, for example 2.3 meters.

We would like to know what will be the best strategy to implement this?

One way that we thought about is to send a constant linear velocity on topic twist.twist.linear.x and stops after a certain time t such as t=distance/velocity.
Is this a good approach?

is there any other better strategy?

Thanks
Anis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60399/how-to-move-turtlebot-for-a-certain-pre-defined-distance/) by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2013-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One approach that is slightly better than timing is to use TF to see how far you've gone. One example I know of is using TF to measure angle in an older piece of code we used to [draw a square on the ground using a TurtleBot](https://code.google.com/p/albany-ros-pkg/source/browse/branches/seminar2011/ex_move/bin/square_with_tf.py). Doing a distance comparison should be even easier than angle comparison. In a straight line, the odometry of a Turtlebot shouldn't be too bad so TF should provide a more repeatable distance than timing (especially over longer distances at slower speeds).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arpit901](https://answers.ros.org/users/26891/arpit901/) on 2016-06-06**:
Broken link

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can send simple goals using MoveBaseAction. It's perfectly explained [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals). In the sample program, you can use 2.3 instead of 1 for `goal.target_pose.pose.position.x` or y. That should do!

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on 2013-04-11**:
Thanks. Yes, it will work, but needs navigation stack. I tried my solution above and it worked for moving forward and backward.  However, for turning an angle, it does not give satisfactory results as the angle rotated is smaller than expected